# ASP.NET core Controller Return ActionResult and Json

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-web-api

I am using asp.net core 3.1 and am trying to determine how to return JSON along with the [IActionResult status codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-3.1) which I started with. It seems like the first Get method I created returned Json as the Android app calling it was able to receive it without any issues. I had a:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<List<MyObject>> Get()
```

In the method I run a database query, fill objects, add them to the list, and return like this:

```
return Ok(objectList);
```

There are also points where I return:

```
return BadRequest(returnValue);
```

When I do the post methods, the Ok() response does not return as Json. Is there any way to return it as Json a value with the Ok in Json? Why does the Get do it automatically and the Post does not? Also, I do want to deliver specific error message for debugging. How have others done this?

Comment: Show the object classes that are working and not working. My gues you forgot to make getters for the objects that are not diplaying: public int Number {get;set;}

Comment: Well that might me the reason. I’m just returning an int, the new ID. I did not want to return the full object, but thought about it. I guess I need a generic object with an ID representing the PK if I don’t return the full object, or just return “Ok”.

Comment: Under normal circumstances, whether it is a post or a get request, json will be successfully returned. Please make sure that you are sending a post request instead of a get request when you call the post method.

Answer (score 0):

Try use package : `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` and `return Json(HttpStatusCode.OK)`.
You can also create object like below and return as Json from API:

```
public int StatusCode { get; set; }
public string Message { get; set; }
```